# Numerical integration problem.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Consider $f(x)$ is good-enough function, s.a. $|\frac{d^kf}{dx^k}| \le A_k$, for some  fixed $k \ge 0$. We want to make an integration formula for approximation the following integral $\int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x) f(x)$ with fixed error $\epsilon$.

My attempt was so : we should divide this integral by two part $\int_0^B + \int_B^\infty$, and find $B$ to be smaller than $\epsilon /2$. Next we need to make a numerical-integration formula for $\int_0^B$, but there is a small problem, dealing with making such formula. We know that $|f^{(k)}| \le A_k$, but we even don't know about lower derivatives. How can we bound them, or how can we make a good-enough approximation? Any hints.

Comment: If the second derivative of $f$ is bounded, then you may consider the [composite trapezoidal rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) with enough intervals (watch out for rounding errors though)

Comment: Also, if the $k$th derivative is bounded (in absolute value) by a constant $c$, then $|f^{(k-1)}(x)|\le |f(0)|+c\cdot |x|$. By working your way upwards through integration, you can bound each derivative by a polynomial

Comment: This polynomial will be bounded on $[0,B]$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch the main problem that $k$ may not be equal to $2$, it's just a some integer number. I thought about repeating integration in $\int_B^\infty$ , because we need this integral be small.

Comment: Basically we will have $$|f(x)|\le |P(x)|$$ where $P$ is some polynomial of $k$th degree. So for some constants $c_1,c_2$ and all $B$ you will have $$\int_B^\infty f(x)\cdot\exp(-x)\,\mathrm dx\le \int_B^\infty |P(x)|\cdot\exp(-x)\,\mathrm dx\le (c_1+c_2\cdot |B^k|)\cdot\exp(-B),$$ which can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $B$ large enough

Comment: Similarly, we also havee $f''(x)\le P(x)$ where $P$ is a polynomial of $k-2$nd degree